# Laravel addSelect

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-data

I have a query, and I'm trying to add a `addSelect()` to it, but it won't work, and I don't know why, according to the docs it seems correct

The query:

```php
return Project::query()
    ->with('client')
    ->with('status')
    ->with('tasks')
    ->with('tasks.user.userAvatar')
    ->with('tasks.user')
    ->addSelect([
        'number_of_tasks' => Task::where('assigned_id', auth()->user()->id)->whereNull('finished_at')->count()
    ])
```

I got this error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '4' in 'field list'
```

If I output it as a raw sql query:

```
"select `4` from `projects`"
```

I am trying to add `select()` to it, to select everything from `Project`, but nothing works, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63390463/10573560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it the wrong way.

This:

```php
Task::where('assigned_id', auth()->user()->id)->whereNull('finished_at')->count()
```

Will result in an int. In this case, I think it's `4`, which gives you the error.

I think you need to have the `addSelect` parameter be an `array<string, Builder>`. Try this:

```php
->addSelect([
    'number_of_tasks' => Task::query()
        ->selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->where('assigned_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->whereNull('finished_at');
])
```

Also, you can eager load multiple relationships within the same `with()` call by passing in an array.

```php
return Project::query()
    ->with([
        'client',
        'status',
        'tasks',
        'tasks.user',
        'tasks.user.userAvatar',
    ])
    ->addSelect([
        'number_of_tasks' => Task::query()
            ->selectRaw('count(*)')
            ->where('assigned_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->whereNull('finished_at'),
    ]);
```